# Open window via focus textfield in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Good afternoon friends , I'm from Brazil and my English is not the best, so I'm using the google translator to be able to describe my problem, first of all I'm sorry the English mistakes.

I am new to extjs and I wonder how do you call a window that already have ready shortly after the User click the textfield , follows the code that is not working ...

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var titleEl = Ext.get("title-bar");
titleEl.update(i18n.rulesConf);
var form = new Ext.form.Form({
    labelWidth : 70,
    url : '../../evt/configprofile.do'
});

form.add(new Ext.form.TextField({
    name : 'meters',
    fieldLabel : i18n.name,
    width : 250,
    allowBlank : false

}), new Ext.form.Checkbox({
    name : 'enabled',
    fieldLabel : i18n.enabled

}), new Ext.form.TextField({
    name : 'meters',
    id : 'meters'
    fieldLabel : i18n.name,
    width : 250,
    allowBlank : false,

}));

Ext.get('meters').on('click', function() {
    dialog_meterSearching.show();
});
```

I put only an excerpt . I wish by clicking textfield meters open my window .

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is version of your ExtJS?
If you only want to open a window when focus on the textfield , you can listen a `focus` event on your Textfield.
Something like this:

```
new Ext.form.TextField({
    name : 'meters',
    id : 'meters'
    fieldLabel : i18n.name,
    width : 250,
    allowBlank : false,
    listeners: {
        focus: function(comp){
            dialog_meterSearching.show();
        }
    }
});
```